# Installing Garmin Device on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, garmin

I am trying to install my Garmin device (garmin gps 18x usb) so that I can use it in ArcMap, but always I am having the following error.

> Unable to detect GPS device on COM ports supported by the hardware.
>   Make sure Your GPS is turned on, connected properly, and sending data.
>   Also review the Baud rate, Stop bits, Data bits, Parity settings for
>   the port on this dialog.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please always include error messages as text so that they are available to future searches.

Comment: Your GPS is a USB device. You probably need to do some port mapping on your machine to expose it as a COM port

Comment: @BenSNadler I think your comment would qualify as a brief answer.

Comment: it's a rather vague answer but I will put it in per your recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Your GPS is a USB device. You probably need to do some port mapping on your machine to expose it as a COM port. This is windows version dependent but you can get [general how-to here](http://support.technologicalarts.ca/docs/USB%20Boards/ConfiguringVirtualCOMports.pdf)